# When using ScrollView in Android there is sooo many duplicated text

Tags: android

this is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is why there is so many duplicated text on my scrollview
I can't figure out why this happen.

this is main activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> list = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    **String sensorInfo = "";
    for (Sensor sensor : list){
        sensorInfo += sensorInfo + sensor.getName() + "\n";  // this code is to make sensorInfo information to String 
    }
    textView.setText(sensorInfo);**      
}
```

[image]
this is my android emulator

the problem is why there is so many duplicated text on my scrollview
I can't figure out why this happen.

Comment: can you show your output then understand what happens

Comment: I added picture thanks

Comment: add `append` logic

Answer (score 2):

You are contacting the **sensorInfo** multiple times. **+=** operator is equivelent to `sensorInfo + sensor.getName()`.

```
  for (Sensor sensor : list){
        sensorInfo += sensorInfo + sensor.getName() + "\n";
    }
```

Replace with

```
for (Sensor sensor : list){
        sensorInfo += sensor.getName() + "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sbSensorInfo = new StringBuilder();
for (Sensor sensor : list){
    sbSensorInfo.append(sensor.getName()).append("\n");
}
textView.setText(sbSensorInfo.toString());
```